# dynamic filtering with dropdown menu

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, verbose_name="Objekt")
    year = models.IntegerField("Jahr")
    monthly_rate = models.DecimalField("Monatsrate", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    paid = models.DecimalField("Tatsächlich Bezahlt (Brutto)", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Building(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, verbose_name="Kunde")
    ...
    billing_begin = models.DateField("Abrechnungsbeginn")

class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Bankname", max_length=64) #Bankname
    account_number = models.IntegerField("Kontonummer") #Kontonummer
    code_number = models.IntegerField("Bankleitzahl") #Bankleitzahl
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    BIC = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Customer(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank)
```

Now I have the following view:

```
class BuildingRateListView(ListView):
    model = Building
    template_name = "Building/building_bank_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuildingRateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        buildings = Building.objects.filter(customer__debitor=True).order_by('customer__bank', 'customer__last_name')

    erg = []
    for b in buildings:
        rate = str(b.rate_set.latest('year')) + "€"
        erg.append(rate)

    context['building_list'] = erg
    banklist = []
    for b in Bank.objects.all():
        bank_list.append(b)
        #some other code here

    context['bank_list'] = bank_list
    return context
```

In my template I have a List of my buildings and a Dropdown with the list of banks.
In the Dropdown I want to select a Bank and show only those Buildings, where the Customer hast the selected bank.
As a beginner I don't know how to make this dynamic query. How to write in my view.py, urls.py and template.html?

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). State your question, then post your code. _"Introduce the problem before you post any code"_ Also, you need to show some effort. You may be ignored otherwise.

Comment: I am not clear how you are relating banks to building, but here you have to use javascript to show buildings on changing of the bank